# Populating a Queue list from another script (c#)

Tags: c#

I have a Queue list script that I'd like to populate using other scripts

Queuelist script

```
public class CreateItemQueue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static CreateItemQueue staticClass;

    private void Awake()
    {
        staticClass = this;
    }

    public struct ItemDetails
    {
        public string tokenName;
    }
    public ItemDetails localItemDetails;
    public Queue localItemQueue = new Queue();

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(localItemQueue.Count);
    }


}
```

Another script trying to populate the queue list

```
public string tokenName;

public void AddItemToQueue()
{
    CreateItemQueue.staticClass.localItemDetails.tokenName = tokenName;

CreateItemQueue.staticClass.localItemQueue.Enqueue(CreateItemQueue.staticClass.localItemDetails);
}
```

the queue counter is always 0

So what I 'm trying to achieve is having this Queue list populated from outside scripts and then run a Dequeue to start doing what I need with the queued items.

Comment: `staticClass` has no `Enqueue` method. Try this: `EnjinCreateItemQueue.staticClass.localItemQueue.Enqueue(EnjinCreateItemQueue.staticClass.localItemDetails);`. I'm not sure why you say that the counter is always 0, as your code should not even compile.

Comment: sorry edited to fix it, still not works

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you one example but i don't know if is it which do you mean:

```
 public class Script1 : MonoBehaviour 
 {
     public List<string> testList = new List<string>();

     void Start()
     {
         testList.Add ("Item 1");
         testList.Add ("Item 2");
         testList.Add ("Item 3");
     }
 }

 public class Script2 : MonoBehaviour 
 {
     Script1 s1;

     IEnumerator Start()
     {
         s1 = GetComponent<Script1>();
         yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
         foreach(string s in s1.testList)
             print (s);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a method that I can call from other classes and populate the list!